# add promocode to the infusionsoft

Tags: php, wordpress, infusionsoft

I have added this code but this is not working. I want the promocodes to be saved in `infusionsoft`

```
$carray = array(
  php_xmlrpc_encode($app->key),
  php_xmlrpc_encode($contactId), 
  php_xmlrpc_encode($creditCardId), 
  php_xmlrpc_encode($payPlanId), 
  php_xmlrpc_encode(array($productId1, $productId2)), 
  php_xmlrpc_encode(array($subscriptionPlanId1, $subscriptionPlanId2)), 
  php_xmlrpc_encode($processSpecials), 
  php_xmlrpc_encode(array($promoCode1, $promoCode2)) // array of strings
);
$app->methodCaller("OrderService.placeOrder", $carray);
```

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want promocodes to be save in infusionsoft

Comment: Are you trying to use existing promo codes, or create new ones on the fly?

Comment: I want to create a new one promocode  and want to save it in infusionsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promo Codes are read-only. This means that, while they can be used during orders and applied to invoices, **you can't add new Promo Codes via the API**.

This is an unfortunate limitation of the InfusionSoft API. Read more in the [Table Documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Table_Documentation).

Comment: I know this is old, but I cannot find anywhere how to add a promocode to my blank invoice. The documentation is so unhelpful. I have my API setup, it creates a blank invoice then once the customer has paid it adds all of the products to it and then marks it as paid. But there is no way to add a promo code to an invoice?